# get variable from a wordpress permalink

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

i have this wp page that display the preview of the products and once click it will send to the other page with full details of the product. Actually this worked on not pretty permalink but hopefully trying to make it search engine friendly

preview page:

```
http://localhost/phone/brand
```

full page:

```
http://localhost/phone/specs
```

sample link:

```
<a href="http://localhost/phone/specs/nokia-3210">NOKIA-3210</a>
```

Then specs/full page will get the "nokia-3210" string from the url to use in the wp query. but this redirect me to 404 page.

How can I go about fixing this? I've read that this can be fixed using .htaccess also rewrite_api, I'm lil confuse what to use. Any help to point me to the right direction?

Comment: We can't view it off your localhost.. Please post your query or code you are trying to pull stuff from the permalinks so we can see what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this but I would guess some changes in the htaccess file would be required to force all visits onto the specs page itself and not treat nokia-3210 as a post/page.

Comment: I think I misunderstood. I thought you were trying to generate the product page dynamically, hence mentioning variable in URL. But am I correct in saying you do actually have a page or post named "Nokia 3210"? In that case try selecting and saving a standard permalink structure as offered in the Wordpress admin. Then apply your own custom one. The change to the standard usually corrects problems like your having.

Comment: yes, you are correct in your first post, I gotta know how to do that.

Comment: This may help but using the entire function as it might be overkill... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91046/creating-a-dynamic-url-structure

Comment: The same code on the page linked above is found on this page. There are various approaches. I would consider using example: ?myproductname=Nokia&myproductid=56342 and here is the other page with more help http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/

Comment: -thank you so much I think I can start from the links you have given... BIG THANKS